# How to Print to PDF, not Save?"

Tags: vba, pdf, outlook

### App Versions:

**Outlook:** Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise
**Adobe Acrobat Pro DC:** version 2022.001.20117

**DISCLAIMER:**
My company has disabled "save as" functionality in Outlook.
Please do not suggest any VBA methods that involve ".SaveAs".

### Question:

I want to print an Outlook email to PDF using the Adobe PDF (driver?) printer:

[image]

**The basic process flow I want to automate:**

1. I will open/select an email that I want to print to PDF
2. I will ctrl+P to print and then select the Adobe PDF as the printer
3. A "Save PDF File As" dialogue box appears
4. Within the dialogue, *set the save location* and *set the filename* and *submit*

I coded steps 1-3. **Step 4 is where my problems begin**.

I have not found a way to simulate the dialogue box process.
I tried AppActivate & SendKeys: the code runs but then it shifts the focus back to the VBE and therefore doesn't do what I need within the print dialogue.

I tried finding VBA code that replicates the backend process of the dialogue. I think the dialogue is a function of Adobe so finding VBA to talk to the process is hard.

I am trying with step 4 to set the save location using a variable then set the filename field using a variable then click save to finish the print process.

Dialogue box and relevant fields:
[image]

*Note: I save attachments using .SaveAsFile as MailItem.SaveAs does not work.*
Skip to the code heading titled, "Print/save email as PDF" to get to the good stuff:

```vb
Sub saveEmail()

'================================================================================
' Initialize variables
'================================================================================
    Dim olSelection As Outlook.selection
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim olTempFolder As String
    Dim myDate As String: myDate = Year(Now) & Month(Now) & Day(Now) & _
                            Hour(Now) & Minute(Now) & Second(Now)
    Dim myPrinter As String
    
    ' Assign PDF printer to variable
    myPrinter = "Adobe PDF"
    
    ' Assign the window title of the save as pdf dialogue
    myDialogueTitle = "Save PDF File As"
    
    
'================================================================================
' Create email download path
'================================================================================
    ' Get the local temp folder path
    tempPath = ""
    tempPath = VBA.Environ("temp")
    
    ' Add Outlook Attachments subfolder to temp path
    olTempFolder = tempPath & "\Outlook Attachments"
    Debug.Print olTempFolder ' Print the folder path to immediate window
    
    ' If the path exists, check to make sure path is a directory, else create
    dirExists = Dir(olTempFolder, vbDirectory)
    If dirExists <> "" Then
        dirAttr = GetAttr(olTempFolder)
        
        ' Check if path is directory (attribute "16")
        If dirAttr <> 16 Then
            MsgBox "There is an error with the specified path. Check code " & _
                "try again."
        End If
        
    Else
    ' If folder does not exist, create
        MkDir (olTempFolder)
        
    End If
    
'================================================================================
' Create unique folder for this run
'================================================================================
    olTempFolder = olTempFolder & "\emailToPDF-" & myDate
    MkDir (olTempFolder)

'================================================================================
' Save attachments from selected email
'================================================================================

    Set olSelection = ActiveExplorer.selection
    Set myItem = olSelection.Item(1)

    For Each olAtt In myItem.Attachments
        attFullPath = olTempFolder & "\" & olAtt.DisplayName
            olAtt.SaveAsFile (attFullPath)
        Next
'===============================================================================    
    ' Print/save email as         
'================================================================================ 

 


    ' Set the default printer
    Set mynetwork = CreateObject("WScript.network")
    mynetwork.setdefaultprinter myPrinter
    
    ' Print the email
    myItem.PrintOut
    
    ' Send keystrokes to Save As dialogue
    AppActivate myDialogueTitle ' Activate the printer dialogue window
    
    SendKeys myDate, True ' Change file name to be saved
    SendKeys "{F4}", True ' Activate path text box
    SendKeys "^a", True ' Select all contents of path text box
    SendKeys "{DEL}", True ' Delete selected contents of text box
    SendKeys olTempFolder, True ' Set desired save path in the path location box
    SendKeys "{ENTER}", True ' Press enter to set the path
    SendKeys "{ENTER}", True ' Press enter to submit/save as

'================================================================================
'
'================================================================================

End Sub
```

Again, please do not suggest a solution involving the ".SaveAs" method. Our IT administrators disabled this functionality in Outlook so VBA code calling it does not work.

Comment: `myItem` is not set anywhere. Is it a mistake, or you didn't want showing what it is?

Comment: This only means it is declared, not set... Anyhow, what you need can be achieved using API calls. But in order to test it, you should set that object. Otherwise, nothing will be printed... I will try posting an answer, but not complete. It will save in the default path (Documents). I must leave my office. I will be able to complete it only after some hours when I will be at home.

Comment: It was a mistake. I pared down the code to make it more readable when I made my post, and the object assignments were incorrectly cut out.

Comment: OK. this was obvious... But do you run the above code from Outlook itself, or like an automation from another application (Excel, for instance)? Otherwise, the shown dialog is not related to Acrobat, it is the Outlook application printing Window... And I cannot understand how you can use `SendKeys` otherwise than like an automation. Did you find some time to test the code I posted? I used iSpy++ to see the windows structure of the dialog and it should be reliable. At least, against `SendKeys`...

Comment: @FaneDuru I am working on getting your code together in my module right now. Also, to answer your first question, I am running this macro from Outlook. My goal is to be able to print my emails to pdf as I am reading through them in Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code I didn't find a place where Outlook objects declared at the beginning of the functions are declared.

```
Dim olSelection As Outlook.selection
Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olAtt As Outlook.Attachment
```

It seems you need to get the currently selected item in the `Explorer` window. Use the `Selection` property of the `Explorer` class which returns a Selection object that contains the item or items that are selected in the explorer window.

```
Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer 
Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection 
For x = 1 To myOlSel.Count 
  If myOlSel.Item(x).Class = OlObjectClass.olMail Then
```

Then you can deal with a selected item. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information. So, you are free to use the [Document.SaveAs2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.saveas2) method which saves the specified document with a new name or format. Some of the arguments for this method correspond to the options in the Save As dialog box (File tab).

Also you may find the [Document.ExportAsFixedFormat2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat2) method which saves a document as PDF or XPS format.

Comment: I am fumbling my way through the Word object model within Outlook VBA. I have successfully saved the email body into a pdf using your suggested method.

What I am now stuck on, is that I want to add the print "memo" headers into the word document. That header is the one that appears at the top of the email when you print an email in Memo style. It contains the Outlook User, To, From, Date, and Subject.

Comment: That is a subject for a separate post. I'd suggest marking the answer and posting a new question separately.

Comment: I went ahead and used this method, even though it completely bypasses the printer. I used the Word object model to call the Word application and recreate the Memo Style printer output in a  word document, then printed it from Word.

Answer (score 1):

In order to handle the Print to pdf dialog proceed in the next way:

1. Copy the next API functions declaration on top of the module (in the declarations area):

```
 Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
                    (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
 Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias _
            "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hwnd1 As LongPtr, _
            ByVal hwnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
            ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                                        ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As Long
```

There are declarations for 64 bit systems (VBA 7). It can be adjusted to work for both cases.

2. Use this way to deal with the dialog handlers, to change the pdf file name and press `Save`:

```
Sub handlePrintToPDF()
  Dim pdfHwnd As LongPtr, hwnd1 As LongPtr, hwnd2 As LongPtr, hwnd3 As LongPtr
  Dim hwndCombo As LongPtr, hwndEdit As LongPtr, hwndSave As LongPtr
  Dim tempPath, olTempFolder As String, myDate As String
    tempPath = VBA.Environ("temp")
    olTempFolder = tempPath & "\Outlook Attachments"
    myDate = Year(Now) & Month(Now) & Day(Now) & Hour(Now) & Minute(Now) & Second(Now) & ".pdf"
    
    Do While pdfHwnd = 0
        DoEvents
        pdfHwnd = FindWindow("#32770", "Save PDF File As"): Debug.Print Hex(pdfHwnd)
    Loop
    hwnd1 = FindWindowEx(pdfHwnd, 0, "DUIViewWndClassName", vbNullString): Debug.Print Hex(hwnd1)
      hwnd2 = FindWindowEx(hwnd1, 0, "DirectUIHWND", vbNullString): Debug.Print Hex(hwnd2)
        hwnd3 = FindWindowEx(hwnd2, 0, "FloatNotifySink", vbNullString): Debug.Print Hex(hwnd3)
          hwndCombo = FindWindowEx(hwnd3, 0, "ComboBox", vbNullString): Debug.Print Hex(hwndCombo)
           hwndEdit = FindWindowEx(hwndCombo, 0, "Edit", vbNullString): Debug.Print Hex(hwndEdit)
           
           Const WM_SETTEXT = &HC
           Dim pdfFileFullName: pdfFileFullName = olTempFolder & "\" & myDate
           
           
           SendMessage hwndEdit, WM_SETTEXT, 0&, ByVal "MyMail pdf" 'use here what you need as pdf docment to be saved name
           
           hwndSave = FindWindowEx(pdfHwnd, 0, vbNullString, "&Save"): Debug.Print Hex(hwndSave)
           Const WM_LBUTTON_DOWN = &H201, BM_CLICK = &HF5
           SendMessage hwndSave, WM_LBUTTON_DOWN, 0&, 0&
           SendMessage hwndSave, BM_CLICK, 0, ByVal 0&
End Sub
```

3. Call the above sub after `myItem.PrintOut`:

```
 handlePrintToPDF
```

But launching the print window (from Outlook) **will block VBA**. I used it as an automation from Excel...

Comment: I tested steps 1 and 2 without calling handlePrintToPDF from my sub. I found that your method compiles correctly and runs fine until the last line where (I think) it is clicking save. The problem is that, although the visible filename was changed, when the VBA clicks save, the program still wants to save the PDF as the default filename that appeared in the filename field when the Save As dialogue window first appears. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: do you know why VBA locks up when the printer output window opens? Because of that one flaw, I cannot use this method, even if I was able to get it to work.

Comment: @Logan Price I cannot understand what does "even if I was able to get it to work" mean... Like I said, **the above solution works only like an automation from another application. I used Excel VBA.**. When the print window is shown, VBA stops working **in that specific session**. This is the way VBA works...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was referencing my first comment I made on June 6th where I explained that I could not get your code to work in my Outlook macro. Do I understand you correctly that regardless of the Office application (Excel, Word, Outlook, etc.), this method will never be able to handle the printer dialogue window? @FaneDuru

Comment: @Logan Price yes, nothing will be able to work with API functions to handle Print windows **in the same VBA session**.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but it sounds like you are alluding that there is a way to manipulate the dialogue window with a different VBA session? So I manually open the printer window in Outlook, and then I run the Macro out of Excel to manipulate it? If I am incorrect, can you specify what you mean by using different VBA sessions for this?

Comment: @Logan Price I am trying to explain that from almost two months... The answer is **yes**. I've written  in my answer: **I used it as an automation from Excel...**